# Two keyboard keys with same ouput?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, keyboard

I have a [Gigabyte Aero 14](https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/AERO-14--GTX-1060#kf/) with the [G-Macro keys](https://unlocked.newegg.com/sites/default/files/gigabyte-aero-14-laptop-review-8.jpg) on the side.  I have had Arch for a while on this computer and love it for my coding environment, but I have had some free time lately and want to finally get these G-keys to work not only in Windows with the [G-Macro Hub](https://img.purch.com/o/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubGFwdG9wbWFnLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvdXBsb2Fkcy9wcHJlc3MvNDQ4NTYvYW9ydXMtbWFjcm8taHViLWRyaXZlci5qcGc=/), but also in Arch with most custom controls.

Apparently, these macros are set in the BIOS of the computer, which means that settings that I have tried out for say inserting a piece of predefined text upon pushing G1 in "red" mode (modes are changes by pushing the main "G" key) will insert that text no matter the OS.  However there are still two limitations.  I would like to be able to define custom functionality from these keycodes specific to my Arch installation to interact with KWin or something like that, and when I actually push the "G" key, my screen brightness gets turned down.

I have used

```
showkey --keycodes
```

to view what data my keyboard is giving to diagnose why my screen brightness gets turned down.  Long behold, the output from pressing Fn + F3  (which is supposed to turn down screen brightness) or the "G" key yields a scancode output of

```
 #Fn + F3:    0xe0 0x4c 0xe0 0xcc 
 #G-key:      0xe0 0x4c
              0xe0 0xcc
```

How can I differentiate between Fn + F3 to turn down screen brightness and the "G" key to switch maco modes?
Additionally, is there a way I can interface with these macro keys/modes within Arch or do I need to manually set their functionality/scancodes in the MacoHub within Windows?

Comment: Use `evtest` and find out if the key events originate from the same input device. If the G-keys simulate a real keyboard, it will be really hard to distinguish them from normal keys, e.g. Fn+F3. To get access to them, first thing I'd do is to try to reverse engineer the G-Macro Hub application, and see how it accesses the G-Key functionality. Looking in the Windows Hardware information for a hardware interface to them may also help.

Comment: dirkt, thank you for the suggestion.  I have used evtest a you suggested, and found that the G keys are on a "E-signal keyboard" device number 21, and the main keyboard is a "E-signal keyboard" device number 18.  

Under the device for the G keys, it has the following event:
Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)

When I press the main G key, an event happens of type 4 (MSC_SCAN), and then a type 1 event is immediately called with code 224 KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN.

Thank you again...

Comment: So in other words, you are still getting the same key events, but they appear on different input layer devices? If yes, you can of course use this to differentiate, but note that as X layer events, they'll be the same. One option would be to "grab" (as in `evtest --grab`, look at the source code) the G-key device, translate them yourself and inject them via `uinput`, but this will require a bit of programming.

Comment: This sounds like a great project.  I am a university student and just finished a project writing my own kernel module, and then USB mouse driver with the inputs subsystem from scratch so this sounds right up my alley, ill look into that, thanks! 

In other thoughts, how did the "KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN" event even get registered with that key event?  Can I just remove this event?

Comment: You can actually do this all from user space, no kernel module needed. But if you are interested, looking at the kernel input layer doesn't hurt. Your hardware will use some proprietary way to register the key sequences for the G-Keys, that's why I suggested reversing the G-Hub application.